# How to read grpc command line tool error messages from the responses?

Tags: go, grpc

I am using the grpc command line tool to test response for my grpc request. This is the official link to the grpc command line tool: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/command_line_tool.md (The usage guide is not updated. Kindly read `~/workspace/src/github.com/grpc/bins/opt/grpc_cli help`)

I am running the command from the location where my protocol file resides. I am sending a request like this, (FYI: I am also sending the metadata. Irrespective of inclusion of the metadata or not I am getting the same error message) :

```
$ ~/my_workspace/src/github.com/grpc/bins/opt/grpc_cli call 0.0.0.0:50051 \  
MyGrpcMethod <name_of_my_proto_file.proto> "abc : '12-34-56-78', xyz: '1234'" \ 
--metadata "auth:<auth_token>:space:xxx:org:xxx" --enable_ssl=false
```

In the response I am getting it says that there are some errors however, it does not show what the errors are. Here is the response I got from my client request:

```
connecting to 0.0.0.0:50051
Failed to read response.
Rpc failed with status code 12 error message unknown service my_agent.MyServiceAPI
```

Right now, I am not able to figure out from the documentation or otherwise on how to read the response. Did anyone face an issue like this?

Comment: Got an answer to the error message. I was reading it wrong.

The part that says "unknown service my_agent.MyServiceAPI" means that the server does not have an implementation of a service with that name, and status code 12 means "unimplemented". This probably means that either your server is misconfigured or that you are not using the right proto file in your grpc_cli invocation. Thanks to Micheal Lumish at grpc.io group!

   However that being said, I have the correct proto file and I do have service implemented with the name I have in my proto file. I will have to dig deep to fix this.